# .net3.5: xml file should not be part of dll?

Tags: .net, xml, dll

I dont want xml files to be part of dll.

I want to change xml files after deploying dll on production.What shd i do?

Answer (score 3):

In the properties for your XML files in your project, set the build action to "content" and "Copy to output directory" to either "Always" or "copy if newer".